# Laravel Blade won't show css

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this blade where I am sending data via compact, and in the url I have the id. But it won't load the css that I am using in other pages.

here is the header code : which is by the way working in other blades. Does anyone have an idea why it is not working here ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @include('header')
    @yield('header')

</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>


<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="content">
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML contain instead? Console errors? Tried whatever  debugging Laravel offers?

Comment: nothing , it just shows the writing without the css . I have used the < a href to get to this page and I send the id via the url using <a href="f/{{$f->id}}">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now fine by using assets instead of simple src .

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.flexslider-min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```